# How to convert document's values into an array using mongodb aggregration?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to achieve this simple thing. I have these 2 documents

```
1: {a="010", b="020", c="030"}
2: {a="030", b="040", c="050"}
```

I need to obtain the following document using mongodb aggregations:

```
{ result = [{a="010", b="020", c="030"}, {a="030", b="040", c="050"}] }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You can group the documents into a single document - use the aggregation `$group` stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
   $group:{
     "_id": null,
     "result": {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
     }
   }
}
```

])

Group all the docs under result as an array.

Comment: Getting a lot of mileage out of this solution.  :-)